# Sorting retrieved data from realtime database in row and columns and implement search view so every row can be searched

Tags: android, json, firebase, kotlin

[the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9446a.png)

`this my Excel class`

```
public class Excel {
        public int Age;
        public String Country;
        public String Date;
        public String First_Name;
        public String Gender;
        public int Id;
        public String Last_Name;
        public String status;

        public Excel() {
        }

        @PropertyName("Age")
        public int getAge() {

            return Age;
        }

        @PropertyName("Country")
        public String getCountry() {

            return Country;
        }

        @PropertyName("Date")
        public String getDate() {

            return Date;
        }

        @PropertyName("First_Name")
        public String getFirst_Name() {

            return First_Name;
        }

        @PropertyName("Gender")
        public String getGender() {

            return Gender;
        }

        @PropertyName("Id")
        public int getId() {

            return Id;
        }


        @PropertyName("Last_Name")
        public String getLast_Name() {
            return Last_Name;
        }


        @PropertyName("status")
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Excel{" +
                    "Age=" + Age +  "" + ", Country='" + Country + '\'' +
                    ", Date='" + Date + '\'' +
                    ", First_Name='" + First_Name + '\'' +
                    ", Gender='" + Gender + '\'' +
                    ", Id=" + Id +
                    ", Last_Name='" + Last_Name + '\'' +
                    ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

`this my Main Activity class`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var coursesLV: ListView? = null
    lateinit var coursesArrayList: ArrayList<Excel>
    lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
   lateinit var Img_set:ImageView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Img_set = findViewById(R.id.Img_set)
        Img_set.setOnClickListener {
            intent= Intent(this,Admin_Info::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        coursesLV = findViewById(R.id.idLVCourses)
        coursesArrayList = ArrayList()
        getdata()
    }

    private fun getdata() {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesArrayList)
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Excel")
        reference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                for (ignored in snapshot.children) {
                    val currentUser = snapshot.getValue(Excel::class.java)!!
                    coursesArrayList.add(currentUser)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            }

            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {}
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        })
        coursesLV!!.adapter = adapter
    }
    }
```

`this is my database structure as json file`

```
{
  "Excel": [
    {
      "Age": 32,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "15/10/2017",
      "First_Name": "Dulce",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 1562,
      "Last_Name": "Abril",
      "status": "open "
    },
    {
      "Age": 25,
      "Country": "Great Britain",
      "Date": "16/08/2016",
      "First_Name": "Mara",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 1582,
      "Last_Name": "Hashimoto",
      "status": "close"
    },
    {
      "Age": 36,
      "Country": "France",
      "Date": "21/05/2015",
      "First_Name": "Philip",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Id": 2587,
      "Last_Name": "Gent",
      "status": "open "
    },
    {
      "Age": 25,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "15/10/2017",
      "First_Name": "Kathleen",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 3549,
      "Last_Name": "Hanner",
      "status": "close"
    },
    {
      "Age": 58,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "16/08/2016",
      "First_Name": "Nereida",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 2468,
      "Last_Name": "Magwood",
      "status": "open "
    },
    {
      "Age": 24,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "21/05/2015",
      "First_Name": "Gaston",
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Id": 2554,
      "Last_Name": "Brumm",
      "status": "close"
    },
    {
      "Age": 56,
      "Country": "Great Britain",
      "Date": "15/10/2017",
      "First_Name": "Etta",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 3598,
      "Last_Name": "Hurn",
      "status": "open "
    },
    {
      "Age": 27,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "16/08/2016",
      "First_Name": "Earlean",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 2456,
      "Last_Name": "Melgar",
      "status": "open "
    },
    {
      "Age": 40,
      "Country": "United States",
      "Date": "21/05/2015",
      "First_Name": "Vincenza",
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Id": 6548,
      "Last_Name": "Weiland",
      "status": "open "
    }
  ]
}
```

I retrieved Data from realtime database and it came in json but I want to sort it in row and columns, can you help sorting this data into such manner that I get age in age row & column and so on , I want to implement search view on this so I can search data by row and columns like excel sheet, is that possible ?

Comment: please do check the image I have attached

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo sir I added my database structure as a json file please do check

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you sir I added following code removed loop, can you please help me on sorting data, I want to sort this data  as row and columns where you can search every row of data

Comment: It's about Firestore, but I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help you create an idea.

Comment: @AlexMamo this really helped but still I am unable to figure out how can I sort this data in row and column manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using a ChildEventListener, there is no need to loop through the children. You should simply use:

```
override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    val currentUser = snapshot.getValue(Excel::class.java)!!
    coursesArrayList.add(currentUser)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Besides that, don't also forget to handle errors:

```
override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    error.message?.let {
        Log.d("TAG", it)
    }
}
```